# Quick-look feature to see build progress in MDriven

Tags: uml, modeling, mdriven

If I want to have a quick look at the results on the website in my work in MDriven, is there perhaps an easy shortcut for me to do that, or else, is the link displayed somewhere in a menu so I can copy it?

I'm using the turnkey package.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your site runnning in the cloud you can use a Sample site. The sample site is requested and is yours for 1 hour.

You will find a "request Demo site" button under https://portal.mdriven.net MyTurnkeySites.

Once you have the demo site you will find it under the cloud icon in MDriven Designer -> upload and you are done